# Using the same Firebase Cloud Messaging server key across multiple service instances

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have multiple instances of the same service across multiple data centers. 
This is the same service, so I can have only one auto-generated Firebase Cloud Messaging server key.

- What will FCM server do, when it receives a request with the same
  server-key from couple services?
- What with refreshing those keys/tokens? How can I achieve, that every instance have the same, active server key?

Answer (score 1):

> What will FCM server do, when it receives a request with the same server-key from couple services?

FCM checks whether the key is authorized to send messages to the current project, and if so it allows it.

The key doesn't identify a service, but merely authorizes it.

Comment: Nice. Thanks. I had the same question. I am also using the same FCM service account key across multiple web server instances which generate push notifications independent of each other.

Comment: Follow-up question: since service account is used to for obtaininng oauth token from FCM does it imply that there are multiple outstanding valid oauth tokens simultaneously ?